# How to save ids to users columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, model, shopping-cart

So I've built a system of products and a shopping cart in my rails app. The goal I have is to add ids of the saved products from a cart to the user model. So in my cart view page there is a list of all added products in a cart and I want to add a save button which will save those products by their ids to the columns in users table. As an example, if current_user ads three products in the cart with ids 1,2,3 and clicks on "Save" button in a cart, I want to be able to save those three ids by integers to the three columns: product_one, product_two, product_three of the current_user.

So far these are my models:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :cart
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :cart
  has_many :items, through: :cart 
end

class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item

  validates_uniqueness_of :user, scope: :item
end
```

My controllers:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_item, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html, :json, :js

  def index
    @items = Item.where(availability: true)
  end 

  def show
  end 

  def new 
    @item = Item.new
  end 

  def edit
  end 

  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
    @item.save
    respond_with(@item)
  end 

  def update
    @item.update(item_params)
    flash[:notice] = 'Item was successfully updated.'
    respond_with(@item)
  end 

  def destroy
    @item.destroy
    redirect_to items_url, notice: 'Item was successfully destroyed.'
  end 

  private
    def set_item
      @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    end 

    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:name, :description, :availability) 
    end 
end
```

my cart controller:

```
class CartController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]


  def add
    id = params[:id]
    if session[:cart] then
      cart = session[:cart]
    else
      session[:cart] = {}
      cart = session[:cart]
    end
    if cart[id] then
      cart[id] = cart[id] + 1
    else
      cart[id] = 1
    end
  redirect_to :action => :index
  end


  def clearCart
    session[:cart] = nil
    redirect_to :action => :index
  end






  def index
    if session[:cart] then
      @cart = session[:cart]
    else
      @cart = {}
    end

  end
end
```

And I'm using Devise for authentication..

Comment: It's strange that your cart belongs_to :item, isn't it? Means user has one cart, and cart is connected (belongs to) just one item. So user will only have one item, right? How you currently envision connecting several items to single user?

Comment: By the way, explain what you want to achive by saving ids of products to user model inside explicit columns. Do you want to "denormalize" storage, i.e. have a "cache" of item ids in user table in addition to normal (relational) connection from user to item through cart? Or do you want to build a connection between user and product by using this approach (i.e. not have an other way from user to items but only through these columns). Anyway, as what's your building is by all means non-standard and, from the first sight, very inefficient way of connection, please explain why are you building it.

Comment: @PavelBulanov It may be a wrong approach. Basically I need to know which products user has selected in order to ship those products. It can be any way these are associated but I need to know merged user id and item id. Just need to get this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have misunderstood the Rails relations and how to use them. As the methods to define relation are pretty much literal, take a good look at your models and 'read' them.

- An item has one cart
- A cart belongs to a item

Does it make sense that an item has one cart? Wouldn't make more sense to a cart to have an item, or several?

- A cart has one or more items
- One item belongs to a cart

And then, you just translate that into rails methods:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :cart
end

class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user #carts table must have a user_id field
  has_many :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cart #items table must have a cart_id field
end
```

Now, let's return to the literals. So, if I have a `user` and want to know what items he has in a cart, what do I do?

- I know a user has one cart
- I know that a cart has one or more items

So, to recover the items that a user has in a cart:

```
user.cart.items
```

And answering your original question, how to save the items to a `user`? You don't need to. If the user has a `cart` and this `cart` has `items` then, automatically, `user` has items (accessing them through the `cart`, as stated above).